# Javascript/jQuery - Display hidden #element when one of the checkboxes is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

**Introduction to problem:**

I'm working on a inquiry form and I have created a checkbox group which contains 5 different valued inputs. What I'd like them to do, is display a hidden #element when at least one of them is selected (except for one checkbox - #ch1).

**HTML**

```
<form>
<div class="group">
    <label>
        <input name="check[]" id="ch1" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
        Option 1
    </label>
    <label>
        <input name="check[]" id="ch2" type="checkbox" value="2"/>
        Option 2            
    </label>
    <label>
        <input name="check[]" id="ch3" type="checkbox" value="3"/>
        Option 3
    </label>
    <label>
        <input name="check[]" id="ch4" type="checkbox" value="4"/>
        Option 4
    </label>
    <label>
        <input name="check[]" id="ch5" type="checkbox" value="5"/>
        Option 5
    </label>
</div>
<div id="hidden">
    <p>Hidden message</p>
</div>    
</form>
```

**jQuery - what i managed to do..**

```
$('input[name="check[]"').click(function(){
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#hidden').toggle('slow');
        }
        else {
            $('#hidden').hide('slow');
        }
});
```

**In conclusion:**

If at least one of the checkboxes (#ch2/#ch3/#ch4/#ch5) or all of them is selected - div #hidden must be visible;

If none of the checkboxes or checbox #ch1 is selected - div #hidden must stay hidden.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnemic/kLmoschb/)

Thank you all in advance!

**EDIT:**
In case if anyone is interested, working fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mnemic/181o9935/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes work wonderfully in this situation. You have many html elements that you want to tie an event to. Try this HTML:

```
<form>
<div class="group">
    <label>
        <input class="checked" name="check[]" id="ch1" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
        Option 1
    </label>
    <label>
        <input class="checked" name="check[]" id="ch2" type="checkbox" value="2"/>
        Option 2            
    </label>
    <label>
        <input class="checked" name="check[]" id="ch3" type="checkbox" value="3"/>
        Option 3  
    </label>
    <label>
        <input class="checked" name="check[]" id="ch4" type="checkbox" value="4"/>
        Option 4
    </label>
    <label>
        <input class="checked" name="check[]" id="ch5" type="checkbox" value="5"/>
        Option 5
    </label>
</div>
<div id="hidden" style="display:none;">
    <p>Hidden message</p>
</div>    
</form>
```

And your JavaScript as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.checked').change(function(){
        if ($('input:checked').length > 0) {
            $('#hidden').show('slow');
        } else {
            $('#hidden').hide('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Not only do you get to use the class to group the elements to the change event but you can use it to check for a 'checked' checkbox. This code will monitor all of the checkboxes for changes and as long as one of them is checked you message will display. Barmar is right about the JavaScript not running at the right time too. You can use jQuery's $(document).ready() to handle that.

Comment: Getting closer, almost what I need! Basically, your way works, but as I mentioned before, I would like this to work for checkboxes 2-5, not for #ch1 .. I thought that removing the class from #ch1 would work and it kind of did, but now #hidden stays visible when #ch1 is checked and I un-check checkboxes 2-5 .. I've updated my fiddle to your solution, If you could check it out, I'd really appreciate it.
check option 2 > check option 1 > un-check option 2 to see what I mean. Thanks again!

Comment: Got it to work as I wanted, after changing 

**if ($('input:checked').length > 0)**

to:

**if ($('.checked:checked').length > 0)**

So bottom line, great answer, would even upvote, if I could. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't use `.toggle` when you want to go to a specific state, you should use `.show` or `.hide`. Second, you're just checking whether the box they clicked on is checked, not whether ANY of the boxes are checked.

Your fiddle wasn't working at all because you didn't put the code the onDomReady handler, so it was running before the DOM was loaded.

```
$('input[name="check[]"').click(function(){
    if ($('input[name="check[]"]:checked').length > 0) {
            $('#hidden').show('slow');
        }
        else {
            $('#hidden').hide('slow');
        }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/kLmoschb/5/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'm sorry, but your solution doesn't seem to work (there was a typographical error, missing < ' > after if ($('input[name="check[]"]:checked <-- ) but even after adding it, it didn't work.. is it just me?

Comment: I fixed that in one of my fiddles, I must have pasted the wrong link. After I fixed it, it worked for me. Unfortunately, jsfiddle.net seems to be down now, I can't find the correct link.